# AngularJS 'sort is undefined in filter

Tags: angularjs

I have created an AngularJS filter that is working very awesome !!!
but the problem with the console. in console, showing error though it is working. now i want to remove the error.

this is error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
    at filter.js:14
```

here you go for my filter:

```
app.filter('filterByName', function () {
    return function (item) {
        return item.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    };
  });
```

Note again, the filter is working fine but only it showing this error in console, my concern with this error.

this is how i used this filter in tempalate:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filterByName track by $index ">
```

I heard of the error is showing  coz, i didnt configure the js version but i dont know what is this and how to do it.

can anyone tell me how can i get rid of this problem?

Optional:

this is where i initialized  Contacts.

```
$scope.getAllContact = function() {
    var data = $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.contacts = response.data;

    }, function(response) {

    });
  };
```

Comment: Before using sort(), you better add a check to ensure 'item' is not undefined , in any case.

Comment: Can you share your code where you have defined/initialized/updated `contacts` in your code?

Comment: I have edited, please check in the end of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because your item is undefined, you can add the following lines to prevent that error.

```
app.filter('filterByName', function () {
    return function (item) {
        if(item == undefined)
            item = []
        return item.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    };
});
```

You can also initialise $scope.contacts = [] in your controller to avoid this issue.